How can I set an OFFSET = 100 in nls (Nonlinear Least Squares) coupled with the SSbiexp or SSasympOFF (self-starting) functions in R?
I am using self-starting functions to estimate the best constants for my models in R software. But it does not allow me to constrain my offset (y=100, x=0) to be 100.
The two component exponential model:
model1=nls(y ~ SSbiexp(x, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2) ,
    data = dat)

The simple exponential model:
model2=nls(y ~ SSasympOff(x, Asym, lrc, c0), 
     data = dat)

I do not know how to constrain the model to have an offset=100. All the other parameters, of course, I would like the self-starting functions to determine.
After a suggestion, I am adding here a reproducible example with the actual data from SSBIEXP:
model_biexp=nls(conc ~ SSbiexp(time,A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2), data = Indometh)

# guessing a possible offset for this data could be y=10...

# trying to set an offset=10 for this data

model_biexpOFFSET=nls(conc ~ SSbiexp(time,A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2) + offset(10), data = Indometh)

which gives the error message:
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
In addition: Warning message:
In nls(conc ~ SSbiexp(Indometh$time, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2) + offset(10),  :
  No starting values specified for some parameters.
Initializing ‘A1’, ‘lrc1’, ‘A2’, ‘lrc2’ to '1.'.
Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model


offset works only in linear models. You can do something like fm1 <- nls(conc + 0.1 ~ SSbiexp(time, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2), data = Indo.1).

@Roland, please post as an answer ...

offset works only for linear models (and you need to pass a variable of the same length as the other variables in the model).
With non-linear models, you can just add an offset to the right-hand side of the formula or subtract it from the dependent variable. If you want to use a selfstarting model, the latter approach is preferable.
nls(conc + 0.1 ~ SSbiexp(time,A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2), data = Indometh)
#works, offset is -0.1

Edit:

However, I would like to constrain only the y value of the x=0. For
instance, when we force a model to pass through the origin by adding +
0.

That is a very different question. You want to do constrained fitting and not provide an offset.
First, we know from the documentation that SSbiexp is the following model:

f = A1*exp(-exp(lrc1)*input)+A2*exp(-exp(lrc2)*input)

From basic maths, we know that

f(0) = A1 + A2

If you want to fit this with constrained intercept, you need to re-parameterize the model to

A1 * exp(-exp(lrc1) * time) + (intercept - A1) * exp(-exp(lrc2)*time)

and then treat intercept as a constant. To help with convergence, we provide the gradients to nls.
fit1 <- nls(conc ~ SSbiexp(time,A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2), data = Indometh)

f <- deriv(
  ~ A1 * exp(-exp(lrc1) * time) + (intercept - A1) * exp(-exp(lrc2)*time),
  namevec= c("A1", "lrc1", "lrc2"),
  function.arg =  c("time", "A1", "lrc1", "lrc2"))

intercept <- 4
fit2 <- nls(conc ~ f(time, A1, lrc1, lrc2), 
           data = Indometh, start = coef(fit1)[-3])
coef(fit2)
#       A1       lrc1       lrc2 
#3.0464960  1.2484564 -0.7385389 

predict(fit2, newdata = data.frame(time = 0))
#[1] 4

plot(conc ~ time, data = Indometh, ylim = c(0, 4.5))
curve(predict(fit2, newdata = data.frame(time = x)), 
      add = TRUE, col = "red", from = 0)
curve(predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(time = x)), 
      add = TRUE, col = "blue", from = 0)
grid()
legend("topright",
       legend = c("unconstrained", "intercept = 4"),
       col = c("blue", "red"),
       lty = 1)



Dear Roland, thanks a lot for your answer. The problem about your solution, is that I am adding , for instance in your model, 0.1  to each of y value. However, I would like to constrain only the y value of the x=0. For instance, when we force a model to pass through the origin by adding + 0.

@KaAm That's a very different question. See my edit.

I am sorry my terminological mistake and thanks for your careful explanation. I though that offset was just another terminology for intercept. In fact, I was trying to find a practical way (o lazy way, if you prefer) to force the intercept using the self-starting functions ... just as practical as adding +0 and forcing the origin... but look like it does not exist...

You seem to have the mistaken assumption that non-linear regression is quite similar to linear regression. There are some fundamental differences due to the non-linearity.

A linear model basically is y = X beta + epsilon, with a design matrix X and a coefficient vector beta. One column of X is all ones and that represents the intercept. It is quite easy to remove that column from the design matrix and that forces the fit through the origin. You can then add an offset easily. A nonlinear model  is y = f(x1, ...) + epsilon for some nonlinear function f. There is no general way to force this function through the origin (or any specific point). The approach always depends on the specific function.

Ops, it is true, you are right. Anyways, thanks for your solution concerning the offset. And if someone have a solution to force the intercept, in a practical way, for the nls+self-starting function I am still on the search.
